# Array integer entered by user mips

Tags: arrays, stack, mips

```
    loop:



la $a0, msg1 #output message
li $v0, 4
syscall
li $v0, 5 #read in user input
syscall
move $t0, $v0 
beq  $t0, -99, endloop
beq  $t1,20,endloop #get user input up to 20 times 

addi $t1, $t1, 1
sw $t0,($t3)
addi $t3,$t3,4

b loop #loop until it reaches 20 

endloop:
```

I cant figure out how to save data entered by user into array.array size be 20 integer and -99 to stop. not including -99 on array.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: After entering first number loop ends. it says invalid integer input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I added the requisite lines and it worked without changing any of your code. Therefore, I suspect the problem was with how you were allocating storage for your array.

```
.data
msg1: .asciiz "> "
.align 2
array: .space 400
.text

main:

    la $t3 array
    loop:

        la $a0, msg1 #output message
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
        li $v0, 5 #read in user input
        syscall
        move $t0, $v0
        beq  $t0, -99, endloop
        beq  $t1,20,endloop #get user input up to 20 times 

        addi $t1, $t1, 1
        sw $t0,($t3)
        addi $t3,$t3,4

        b loop #loop until it reaches 20 

    endloop:

    jr $ra
```

Firstly, I used `.space 400` to allocate 400 bytes of storage, enough for 100 integers to store the array. Importantly, and perhaps what you were missing is that before the `.space 400` I have the directive `.align 2` which enforces that the array is word-aligned.